.NET 8 in Winforms removes code in designer.cs, how to avoid this?
We have a Winforms project upgraded to .NET 8. The conversion had only a few problems that where easily fixed, so we continued on this path.
However, now I found a problem that I suspect is a bug in Winforms designer on .NET 8.
I have a custom control, and a panel on that control marked as a "dropzone", so you can drop controls on this custom control in the designer. This worked well until the move to .NET 8.
Here is a snippet of the custom control's code:
[Designer(typeof(UserControlDesigner))]
[Serializable]
public partial class gttDXGridDashboard : UserControl
{ 
  // define a property called "DropZone"
  [Category("Appearance")]
  [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
  public PanelControl DropZone
  {
      get { return panelControlCustom; }
  }

  // ...
}

public class UserControlDesigner : ParentControlDesigner
{
    public override void Initialize(IComponent component)
    {
        base.Initialize(component);

        if (Control is gttDXGridDashboard dashboard)
        {
            bool result = EnableDesignMode(dashboard.DropZone, "DropZone");
            // this writeline never shows, maybe because it's in a control from the toolbox ?
            Console.WriteLine($"EnableDesignMode(dashboard.DropZone, \"DropZone\") = {result}");
        }
    }
}

The PanelControl is from devexpress, it is a container control based on Panel
Now for the problem: in a form that has a gttDXGridDashboard on it, and has a button in the dropzone, the designer.cs looks like this:
  // gttDXGridDashboardList.DropZone
  // 
  this.gttDXGridDashboardList.DropZone.Controls.Add(this.gttDXSimpleButtonAddMultipleChassis);

This worked well while the project was running on the .NET framework, but since the move to .NET 8, this line in the designer.cs is removed from the moment I drop another control on the dropzone, or even when I for example move the existing button (gttDXSimpleButtonAddMultipleChassis) a bit to the right or left
At that moment, the button gttDXSimpleButtonAddMultipleChassis still exists on the form, but has no parent anymore and thus is invisible and unusable.
I tried updating all packages, rebuilding all sources, restarted VS, but no results.
Then I wanted to make a workaround, and write some code that will put all the controls without a parent back onto the dropzone, but I don't know how to search for controls that have no parent, I cannot loop over this.Controls because these controls have no parent anymore.
So I need a little help here.

Did I do something wrong with defining the dropzone?
Is this a know bug/problem and if so is there a fix/workaround?
If all fails, how can I find controls that have no parent?

I know I can always write code in the forms that have this problem to put the controls back, but that would mean writing almost the same code again in several forms, I want a more generic workaround.
EDIT
I put a custom button on the dropzone, so I could override it's parent changed event like this
protected override void OnParentChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnParentChanged(e);

    string newParent = "null";
    if (this.Parent != null)
    {
        newParent = this.Parent.Name;
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"gttDXSimpleButtonAddMultipleChassis parent has changed to {newParent}");
}

I hoped to find more information on when/who changes the parent, but this event only fired once, when the parent was set to the dropzone, but it did not fired anymore when I moved the button a bit and the line was removed from the designer.cs
So either it still has a parent or the removing of that line did not cause the parent to become null yet.
It is a very tricky problem to figure out
EDIT 2
I put a new custom control on a test form, and dropped 2 buttons on the "dropzone", it turns out the designer.cs wants to do it different now in .net8, the result in designer.cs was this
            gttdxGridDashboard1.Controls.Add(button3);
            gttdxGridDashboard1.Controls.Add(button2);

So I am convinced now that in .net8 the ParentControlDesigner is not working anymore, causing the EnableDesignMode to never happen.
Another hint of this is that the onDragOver override in the ParentControlDesigner also does not seems to work anymore, in dotnet framework it prevented the programmers from dropping controls on other parts then the dropzone but now it simple does nothing anymore, it looks like this
        // prevents dropping of controls onto non-Design-mode enabled areas
        protected override void OnDragOver(DragEventArgs de)
        {
            de.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        }


What is a PanelControl?

@shingo It's the panel from devexpress, a custom control from devexpress based on Panel. I put this info in the question also, thanks for pointing this out

@shingo I studied the possible duplicate in more detail, and I was able after all to get a fix from it. Thank you, but I already edited the question before so how can I still close it as solved by a duplicate ?

Great, if that solved your question, just leave this alone.
